# await inside lambda anonymous method which returns value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

I'm doing a select on a repo and inside the anonymous lambda I'm building a model to return but inside that I need to make another async query to get some data. It gives an error where it's saying it cannot return a `Task<MyReturnType>` to `MyReturnType`. I get the `userRepo.Select()` is returning `IEnumerable<Task<UserModel>>` but not sure what to do about it to satisfy the task.

```
var allUsers = userRepo.Select(async u => 
{
   var myUserModel = new UserModel
   {
      Id = u.Id
   };

   myUserModel.Address = await GetAddress(u.Id);

   return myUserModel.
}).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `MyReturnType` exactly?

Comment: Was just giving a generic idea of the error message, but in my example it would be UserModel

Comment: You need to use `var actualUsers=await Task.WhenAll(allUsersTasks)` on that list to await all of the tasks to complete. What does `GetAddress` do though? Executing 100 concurrent SQL queries that return 1 value may be a lot slower than a single query with an `IN` clause that returns the matching values for a list of IDs

Comment: @user441521 just one `UserModel`, not a collection?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's just a simplified example to illustrate the issue. This isn't my exact business problem as I'd prefer not to show all of that here. I did what you said but it didn't like that as "GetAddress()" queries a DbContext and it didn't like that.

Comment: @GuruStron A collection correct, sorry my fault in poorly explaining that.

Comment: If EF Core is used you **can't** use multiple concurrent tasks. DbContext isn't thread-safe and doesn't have to be. You can *easily* write `db.Context.Users.Where(u=>ids.Contains(u.Id)).Select(u=>new {u.Id, u.Address});` to generate `SELECT ID, Address FROM Users where ID in (@id1, @id2, @id3,....)`

Comment: Which means you do have to post the actual code and explain the actual business problem because what you try to do now can only cause delays and overcomplicate the code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah I see. I'll just use a foreach loop then and call it a day. Thanks!

Comment: No don't. Post the actual code and write a *good* query. What you try to do right now can easily be orders of magnitude slower than a simple LINQ query if not worse. If you use a loop, you'll take N times longer. If you use N queries you could end up with N^2 if the queries block each other. Or not. If all you want is query a field based on a primary key, for small numbers the network overhead will be greater than the query itself, so 1 "big" query won't take more than multiple single-row queries

Comment: @user441521 performance 101 - avoid calling database in loop to fetch single records by id.

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, I do understand. There are no FK's setup between these 2 tables and the example uses the idea of getting data in 2 different spots on purpose to illustrate 2 tables are required in the example situation. If a FK was setup I could could the data needed the way ppl are thinking here.

Comment: FKs are constraints, not relations. You don't need an FK *constraint* to do a JOIN or define a relation in EF. If the JOIN columns are indexed, the performance will be the same. Even if they aren't, scanning a table once to find 100 rows is faster than scanning the same table 100 times.

Comment: Besides, EF deals with *entities* not tables. It maps (multi)entity operations into SQL so you don't have to. I suspect you used the "repository" antipattern to generate CRUD classes over tables when you already have an in-memory entity model and relations. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Inside OnModelCreating() and the entity I just now created the relationship and it works now with no need to have the lambda be async. I was saying Fk because if you have them those relationships get setup for you when you generate things but I get what you're saying.